# При установки Android приложения через Facebook, не срабатывает AppsFlyer

Tags: android, facebook

Я связал AppsFlyer с Facebook, в личном кабинете AppsFlyer во вкладке Integrated Partner. Если приложение скачивается по ссылке Аппсфлаер, то все хорошо срабатывает(в приложение внедрено AppsFlyer SDK, а также AppsFlyerConversionListener). А если приложение скачивается по рекламе в ФБ, то по идее, так как я указал партнера в AppsFlyer - Facebook, у меня должен сработать тот же метод onConversionDataSuccess, что и в AppsFlyer. Но, увы, AppsFlyer вообще не срабатывает походу. Помогите, пожалуйста, правильно связать все это дело.
**P.S.** Вопрос задаю впервые, так что если что-то не добавил, то добавлю

[image: Что мы видим в AppsFlyer]
[image: App Id Facebook]

Comment: У меня был опыт работы с AppsFlyer на позапрошлой работе, и там всё непросто) Советую написать им в тех.под, вряд ли здесь будет кто-то хорошо разбирающийся. Либо попробуйте на eng SO, там вероятность ответа выше, как минимум, там [есть такой тэг](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appsflyer).

Comment: Окей, понял. Спасибо) Пойду искать, но надеюсь, что кто-то ответит тут все таки